# How to split observable into chunks by length in F#

Tags: .net, f#

How divide the observable into chunks where each chunk length is n

For example:

observable emits events  `a, b, c, d, e, f ..`  and length 3

as result emits [a;b;c], [d, e, f], ...

splitIntoChunks: int -> IObservable<'a> -> IObservable<'a list>

`splitIntoChunks len observable = ?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a built-in function called [Seq.chunkBySize](https://bradcollins.com/2015/10/09/f-friday-the-seq-chunkbysize-function/) that does this.

Answer (score 5):

For working with Observables there's [FSharp.Control.Reactive](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Control.Reactive) providing wrappers around [Reactive Extensions](http://reactivex.io/) [for .NET](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive), so

```
#r "nuget: System.Reactive"
#r "nuget: FSharp.Control.Reactive"

open FSharp.Control.Reactive

Observable.generate
    (0,1)
    (fun _ -> true)
    (fun (l, c) -> (c, l + c))
    snd
|> Observable.bufferCount 3
|> Observable.take 5
|> Observable.subscribe (printfn "%A")
```

yields

```
seq [1; 1; 2]
seq [3; 5; 8]
seq [13; 21; 34]
seq [55; 89; 144]
seq [233; 377; 610]
```

If you need a list, just add `|> Observable.map Seq.toList` e.g. before subscribing.

---

## First version, including NIH

For working with Observables I would leverage [Reactive Extensions](http://reactivex.io/) [for .NET](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive) to create thin wrappers

```
#r "nuget: System.Reactive"

open System.Reactive.Linq

let chunkBySize (chunkSize : int) observable =
    Observable.Buffer(observable, chunkSize)

let take (count : int) observable =
    Observable.Take(observable, count)
```

and use them like this

```
Observable.Generate(
    (0,1),
    (fun _ -> true),
    (fun (l, c) -> (c, l + c)),
    fun (_, r) -> r)
|> chunkBySize 3
|> take 5
|> Observable.subscribe (printfn "%A")
```

which yields the same result as above

Comment: Why `take 5` ? For instance, why not take 3, 4, or 6?

Comment: @ScottHutchinson no specific reason... I tend to use 'well known' numbers such as 3.141, 2.718, 1.314, 42 and small primes for examples. 3 is used already, 7 too large -> 5 :-)

Comment: Let me ask it a different way. Given a chunk or buffer size of 3, what effect does take 5 have? Why is the take value two more than the chunk size?

Comment: @ScottHutchinson ah, the take count is not related to the chunk size. The `take` is there only to 'cut' the observable after 5 groups of 3 items. Otherwise we would continue to print indefinitely.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like below (untested and based on http://fssnip.net/7Z/title/Sliding-window-for-Observable).

```ml
open System

module Observable =

  /// Returns an observable that yields chunks of 
  /// containing elements drawn from the input observable. 
  /// Each chunk is returned as a fresh array.
  let chunkBySize (count:int) (source:IObservable<_>) =
    { new IObservable<_> with
        member x.Subscribe observer =
            // Start an agent that remembers chunks of length 
            // smaller than the count (new agent for every observer)
            let agent = MailboxProcessor.Start(fun agent ->
                // The parameter 'lists' contains partial lists and their lengths
                let rec loop lists = async { 
                  // Receive the next value
                  let! value = agent.Receive()

                  let chunks =
                    ((0, []) :: lists)
                    |> List.chunkBySize count 
                  
                  // Send all chunks to the observer (as arrays)
                  for c in chunks do
                    observer.OnNext(c |> Array.ofSeq |> Array.rev) 
                }

                // Start with an empty list of partial lists
                loop []
            )

             // Send incoming values to the agent
             source.Subscribe (agent.Post) 
    }
```